# Echoing a CSS class based on category of post in a list

Tags: php, loop, categories

## What I want to accomplish

I need an aside to pull the last 5 posts from a specific set of 5 categories.

Not the latest of each, not the last 5 of each, but the last 5 total posts from the 5 categories.

The category IDs are: 89,90,91,92,93

## Background

I have 5 different category pages, so this has been making it trickier. Each of these uses an include for the aside. I am writing that logic in that include.

### PHP

```
<?php 
    if ( in_category( 92, $post_id ) ) : ?>
    $bfaCat = 'bfa-cat-ba';

<?php endif; ?>
```

Then I have to loop through. Not applying anything if the post is not in any of the categories. But if the posts are of that category then add a variable (as `$bfaCat`) with the following class (on right) applied if it has the following category id (on left)

```
89 - bfa-cat-bl
90 - bfa-cat-fs
91 - bfa-cat-s1
92 - bfa-cat-ba
93 - bfa-cat-ea
```

### HTML - ATTEMPT 1 - in template

```
<div class="bfa-category <?=$bfaCat;?>">
    <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>
```

### HTML - desired output example

```
<div class="bfa-category bfa-cat-bl">
    <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>
```

### HTML - ATTEMPT 2 - Would this be better if modified?

I know this is sloppy but I also tried it inline but it just applied this class to everything

```
<div class="bfa-category <?php if (get_category('91')) echo 'bfa-cat-s1'; ?>">
    <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>
```

So it seems like the class is being echoed into everything.

Comment: What happens if you replace `get_gategory( '91' )` with `in_category( 91 )` or `in_category( 91, ... post id ... )` within your `WP_Query` loop in attempt #2?

Comment: @birgire I read this after finding a solution, would you suggest that I do it differently? What you wrote made more sense than my initial thoughts on the second solution i tried.

Comment: You might simplify it by using an array. If `bl`, `fs`, ... are category slugs, I wonder if you can just prefix the current category slug(s) with `bfa-cat-` and skip the `if` check part.

Answer (score 1):

`get_category('91')` is always going to return an object of category ID 91's data. This means your if statement is always going to return as true. You need to get the current iterated posts assigned category ID and then check if it is 91.

```
<!-- Return objects of current iterated posts associated categories -->
$categories = get_the_category();
<!-- Get current iterated posts assigned category ID from $categories object. The [0] is because a post can be assigned to multiple categories. 
In your example you are probably only assigning one category per post, so you just need to grab the ID of the first category in the returned object. -->
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
<!-- Check if current iterated assigned posts category ID is equal to 91 -->
<div class="bfa-category <?php if ($category_id == 91) echo 'bfa-cat-s1'; ?>">
    <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Ok so based on that I finished the loop for my solution and it works in my project.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coding based on help. I used the PHP suggested to get assign the category.
    cat_ID;
    ?>

Then below it I put that above the actual element where I created the logic to assign the appropriate class

### PHP

```
<div class="bfa-category 
    <?php 
        if ($category_id == 89) {
            echo 'bfa-cat-bl';
        } elseif ($category_id == 90) {
            echo 'bfa-cat-fs';
        } elseif ($category_id == 91) {
            echo 'bfa-cat-s1';
        } elseif ($category_id == 92) {
            echo 'bfa-cat-ba';
        } elseif ($category_id == 93) {
            echo 'bfa-cat-ea';
        }
    ?>">
    <?php the_category(); ?>
</div>
```